# TextView inside a CustomView inside a ListView is truncating horizontally

Tags: android, listview, custom-view

I'm using a `TextView` inside a a "LabeledTextView" component (Basically, a TextView whose label moves from one side to the other when dealing with Layout changes caused to due Right to Left languages). I'm using this inside a ListView and this is occuring:

[image]

The last line of text is being truncated horizontally. Is this perhaps a bug in Android's TextView `onMeasure()` ?

This same "LabeledTextView" component is used in other situations and is working completely fine, so I'm thinking this has something to do with the interaction between it and the `ListView`.

The corresponding part of the list item xml looks like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.test.library.view.LabeledTextView
        android:id="@+id/sender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:label="@string/sender"
        custom:labelWidth="130dp"/>      

    <com.test.library.view.LabeledTextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:label="@string/message"
        custom:labelWidth="130dp"/>                

</LinearLayout>
```

You can see that in the containing LinearLayout I've ensured the height of the container isn't curtailing the size.

The custom view sets the `LayoutParams` as `WRAP_CONTENT` for height - you can see it's grown to be *almost* the correct size.

**EDIT**

When increasing the size of the LabeledTextView manually however, the `TextView` is displaying correctly so I think the default `onMeasure()` of my Custom View isn't correctly accounting for the `TextView` childs height.

Comment: your linearLayout height is set to 400dp,  why not try wrap_content ?

Comment: I specifically increased it from wrap_content in order to ensure that the container wasn't responsible for the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different Linear Layout for the two columns you need to display the answer.

ie. one for the sender and one for the message